# How do I get the Silverlight Pivot Server application to run on IIS 6?

Tags: silverlight, iis-6, httphandler, pivotviewer

How do I get the [Pivot Server Application](http://www.getpivot.com/) to run on IIS 6? The handlers for the cxml don't seem to be registering properly, because I get a 404 for requests to .cxml files.

The closest solution I can see so far is on http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/192470/454278.aspx , but this doesn't seem to be the right way to do it. I see the handlers in the web.config under both system.webserver/handlers and system.web/httpHandlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the extension mappings proposed by gsimard on the [pivot forum](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/192470/454278.aspx), reprinted here for convenience:

```
    In IIS 6 --> properties of the web application --> Directory tab --> Configuration ...
  I have added the following :
    - Executable: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
   Extension: .cxml
   Limit to: GET
   Script engine: checked
   Verify that file exists: unchecked
    - Executable: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
   Extension: .dzc
   Limit to: GET
   Script engine: checked
   Verify that file exists: unchecked
    - Executable: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
   Extension: .dzi
   Limit to: GET
   Script engine: checked
   Verify that file exists: unchecked
At that point, the sample was able to run but no image was displayed. Then I thought that I could also add JPG.

    - Executable: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll
   Extension: .jpg
   Limit to: GET
   Script engine: checked
   Verify that file exists: unchecked
```

...the mime types section in `<system.webserver>` also needs to be uncommented:

```
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".cxml" mimeType="text/cxml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".dzc" mimeType="text/xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".dzi" mimeType="text/xml" />
    </staticContent>
```

Everything worked at this point.