# PivotViewer unable to display collection - only shows link to cxml file

Tags: silverlight, pivotviewer

I have been trying to develop a pivot viewer dynamic collection (from sample source code). My environment is IIS 6, Windows server 2003 and VS 2010. The collection works fine from VS2010, but when i publish the service through VS2010, the collection does not load. The main page is shown with only the link to cxml file. I have added the three mime entries and clientaccesspolicy.xml is already copied by VS. Is there something missing in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Fiddler**](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to check the traffic with the app, where does it get stuck, does it get the `.cxml` file, can it find the `dzi` and `dsc` files?

Did you add dzi and dzc mime types as allowed?

You can see this `Stackoverflow` question to learn how to do this in `IIS 6`:

[How do I get the Silverlight Pivot Server application to run on IIS 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525782/how-do-i-get-the-silverlight-pivot-server-application-to-run-on-iis-6)

Aslo in case you are using the JIT sample code then in the PivotServer project there is web.config file where there are httpHandler configuration values that are meant to be used when running in VS only.

**You should remove those when you're deploying:**

> The Visual Studio Development Server
>   uses these **httpHandler** configuration
>   values. To run the server under **IIS**,
>   comment these handlers so that IIS
>   will use the duplicate set of handlers
>   in the **system.webServer** section below.

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add path="*.cxml" verb="GET" type="PivotServer.CxmlHandler"/>
    <add path="*.dzc" verb="GET" type="PivotServer.DzcHandler"/>
    <add path="*.dzi" verb="GET" type="PivotServer.DziHandler"/>
    <add path="*/dzi/*_files/*/*_*.jpg" verb="GET" type="PivotServer.DeepZoomImageHandler"/>
    <add path="*_files/*/*_*.jpg" verb="GET" type="PivotServer.ImageTileHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a handler to the Loading Fail event and look at the exception?

```
     PivotViewer.CollectionLoadingFailed += new EventHandler< CollectionErrorEventArgs >( PivotViewer_CollectionLoadingFailed );
```